# How to load google translate page window in iframe

Tags: translate

How to Load Google translate Page Window in iframe.

I cant load google translate Below Coding,

Your browser does not support iframes.

My page Is empty Please tell me solution How to load this window?

I want to show Google translation window in my site,

Is there anyother way to show google translation page?

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate has a limitation that you cannot rewrite an iframe content, but you can translate it as listed in this below link

[Google Translate iframe workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936421/google-translate-iframe-workaround)

Additional Info
[Is it possible to auto-translate an Iframe with google translation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622495/is-it-possible-to-auto-translate-an-iframe-with-google-translation)

Comment: Hi, I want to show this url https://translate.google.co.in/ load in iframe,I am not trying to whole site to translate.What is the Use google translate Api?I can Show My page When Using this google translate Api key.